# Error was: No module named util in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

My code throws the error, `No module named util`. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import os
import mongoengine 

DATABASES = 
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
    'NAME'  : 'newdb',
    'USER': 'admin',  
    'PASSWORD': 'admin',  
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
    'PORT': '27017',  
    'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
  },
```

i'm getting following errors...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 
  0x7f7d86a93938>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in 
  inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, 
 in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 134, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named util
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show full stacktrace

Comment: @Satevg  , my error is  Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named util

Comment: I installed mongoengine driver for mongodb

Comment: Can you see it when you do `pip freeze | grep mongodb-engine` ?

Comment: @Satevg ., it's returned django-mongodb-engine==0.6.0  ,when i executed pip freeze | grep mongodb-engine

Comment: Check please this issue https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/167 It's suggested to reinstall `djangotoolbox` package

Comment: @Satevg - its not getting installed django-nonrel-1.5-beta

Comment: There hasn’t been a new release of `django-mongodb-engine` for several years, so it doesn’t work with supported version of Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using older version of Django just upgrade the Django Version. The problem will fix automatically.
Check it similiar question 
[Django no module named utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490876/django-no-module-named-utils)

Comment: my django version is  1.11

Comment: Then this error related to mongodb package. Check the package by typing pip freeze